# Could this list of ciphersuites be improved on?

Tags: java, ciphers

During my self-teaching about trying to find mobile application vulnerabilities, I found a list of cipher suites that are/were considered insecure:

```
md5 sha1 sha-1 md4 rc4 des tripledes 3des
```

If I grepped for these terms in some decompiled Java code and got hits, would it be safe to say, there is a problem?

Comment: Those aren't ciphersuites, and half of them aren't even ciphers, and crypto algorithm names are usually given in uppercase not lowercase (although often especially in JCA case doesn't matter). Java code that uses the algorithm commonly called triple-DES actually names it DESEDE (in either case: often DESede and sometimes desede etc) for historical reasons, _except_ when in a SSL/TLS ciphersuite name. And although there have been a _few_ actual algorithm vulnerabilities (like RC4 in WEP) most vulnerabilites are in the applications and protocols, not the crypto itself.

Answer (score 6):

A simple grep would not provide enough context to determine if there is a problem. Even if your find actual uses for these less secure algorithms (contrary to just finding code which uses these names for other things) it is still not clear if there is a real problem. For example, MD5 and SHA-1 are no problem when used as HMAC. Thus, you actually need to look at what these algorithms are used for.

Comment: Hello Steffen, So if I read you right, I should then do a code crawl to get the context in which I am seeing results from my grep?

Comment: Yes. An automated scan alone (even a simple one just using grep) is never proof of a vulnerability. You always need to follow up with context to ensure it's a true positive.

Comment: But that said, *if* these ciphers are being used for HTTPS communication between a client and server, then it's definitely worth fixing.

Comment: @AngeloSchilling: Claiming that these algorithms are unsuitable for HTTPS in general is not specific enough and essentially wrong. SHA-1 is still often used as HMAC in TLS ciphers (and therefore HTTPS). And there is nothing wrong with this. Even MD5 would be sufficient for this purpose. And the combination of MD5 and SHA-1 is used to construct the PRF in TLS 1.1 and this is not a problem either. If instead MD5 would be used as signature algorithm inside a certificate then it is definitely critical and also SHA-1 is deprecated for this kind of use.